# Encoding problems importing

Tags: postgresql, utf-8

I am having trouble importing a csv to postgres. I import using UTF8 encoding. I am returned the error:

ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xcc 0xc1
CONTEXT: COPY a_household , line 2

When I open the file in Notepad++ it says at the bottom it is encoded in UTF-8 w/o BOM. All the text is displayed - all characters appear to display correctly.

The hexdump (suggested below) returns

```
00000060  2D 32 33 2E 39 32 35 38-37 33 39 32 2C 33 32 2E  -23.92587392,32.
00000070  37 33 32 31 38 33 30 33-2C 37 35 2E 31 32 32 36  73218303,75.1226
00000080  32 39 33 31 2C 34 2C 31-2C 61 62 6F 76 65 31 79  2931,4,1,above1y
00000090  72 2C 31 37 2C 2C 58 61-6E 67 61 6E 61 2C 56 65  r,17,,Xangana,Ve
000000A0  6C 68 61 20 61 70 6F 73-74 6F 6C 6F 2C 53 69 6D  lha apostolo,Sim
000000B0  2C 47 72 69 70 65 20 4D-61 6C CC C1 72 69 61 2C  ,Gripe Mal..ria,
000000C0  50 72 61 74 69 63 61 6E-74 65 5F 64 65 5F 6D 65  Praticante_de_me
000000D0  64 69 63 69 6E 61 20 50-72 CC 5F 70 72 69 6F 2C  dicina Pr._prio,
000000E0  4D 65 64 69 63 61 6D 65-6E 74 6F 73 5F 64 61 5F  Medicamentos_da_
000000F0  66 61 72 6D CC C1 63 69-61 2C 36 2C 4E CC A3 6F  farm..cia,6,N..o
00000100  2C 2C 31 34 2C 4E CC A3-6F 2C 22 44 65 5F 62 6F  ,,14,N..o,"De_bo
00000110  72 6C 61 2C 5F 63 6F 6D-5F 61 75 74 6F 72 69 7A  rla,_com_autoriz
00000120  61 CC A4 CC A3 6F 22 2C-2C 2C 35 2C 41 72 65 69  a....o",,,5,Arei
00000130  61 20 65 20 65 73 74 61-63 61 73 2C 43 68 61 70  a e estacas,Chap
00000140  61 73 5F 64 65 5F 5A 69-6E 63 6F 2C 41 72 65 69  as_de_Zinco,Arei
00000150  61 2C 4C 65 6E 68 61 2C-4E 61 64 61 2C 4C 61 74  a,Lenha,Nada,Lat
00000160  72 69 6E 61 5F 6D 65 6C-68 6F 72 61 64 61 2C 50  rina_melhorada,P
00000170  61 72 61 5F 6D 65 6D 62-72 6F 73 5F 61 67 72 65  ara_membros_agre
00000180  67 61 64 6F 5F 66 61 6D-69 6C 69 61 72 2C 4C 61  gado_familiar,La
00000190  67 6F 61 2F 6C 61 67 6F-2C 50 6F CC A4 6F 5F 70  goa/lago,Po..o_p
000001A0  CC BC 62 6C 69 63 6F 5F-61 62 65 72 74 6F 2C 37  ..blico_aberto,7
000001B0  2C 50 CC A9 2C 30 2C 2C-30 2C 2C 4E 75 6E 63 61  ,P..,0,,0,,Nunca
000001C0  2C 32 2C 50 6F 72 5F 61-6E 6F 2C 52 61 72 61 6D  ,2,Por_ano,Raram
000001D0  65 6E 74 65 2C 52 61 72-61 6D 65 6E 74 65 2C 4D  ente,Raramente,M
000001E0  CC C1 2C 32 35 2C 4E CC-A3 6F 2C 54 65 72 72 61  ..,25,N..o,Terra
000001F0  5F 70 65 72 74 65 6E 63-65 6E 74 65 5F 61 5F 65  _pertencente_a_e
00000200  73 74 61 5F 61 6C 64 65-69 61 2C 4E 75 6E 63 61  sta_aldeia,Nunca
00000210  2C 2C 2C 4D 61 69 73 5F-6F 75 5F 6D 65 6E 6F 73  ,,,Mais_ou_menos
00000220  5F 61 5F 6D 65 73 6D 61-2C 4E CC A3 6F 2C 2C 4D  _a_mesma,N..o,,M
00000230  61 69 73 5F 66 CC C1 63-69 6C 5F 64 65 5F 6F 62  ais_f..cil_de_ob
00000240  74 65 72 2C 2C 53 69 6D-2C 4E CC A3 6F 2C 2C 2C  ter,,Sim,N..o,,,
00000250  2C 4E CC A3 6F 2C 53 69-6D 2C 56 61 63 61 73 2C  ,N..o,Sim,Vacas,
00000260  32 20 34 2C 2C 53 69 6D-2C 31 2C 53 69 6D 2C 6A  2 4,,Sim,1,Sim,j
00000270  61 6E 65 69 72 6F 20 66-65 76 65 72 65 69 72 6F  aneiro fevereiro
00000280  20 6D 61 72 CC A4 6F 20-61 62 72 69 6C 20 6D 61   mar..o abril ma
00000290  69 6F 20 6A 75 6E 68 6F-20 6A 75 6C 68 6F 20 61  io junho julho a
000002A0  67 6F 73 74 6F 2C 31 30-30 2C 53 61 63 6F 73 2C  gosto,100,Sacos,
000002B0  30 2C 4D 61 69 73 5F 64-6F 5F 71 75 65 5F 75 6D  0,Mais_do_que_um
000002C0  61 5F 76 65 7A 2C 53 61-75 64 65 2C 4E CC A3 6F  a_vez,Saude,N..o
000002D0  2C 4E CC A3 6F 2C 2C 2D-39 39 38 2C 53 69 6D 2C  ,N..o,,-998,Sim,
000002E0  4D 75 69 74 6F 5F 73 61-74 69 73 66 65 69 74 6F  Muito_satisfeito
000002F0  2C 4D 75 69 74 6F 5F 73-61 74 69 73 66 65 69 74  ,Muito_satisfeit
00000300  6F 2C 4D 75 69 74 6F 5F-73 61 74 69 73 66 65 69  o,Muito_satisfei
00000310  74 6F 2C 49 6E 73 61 74-69 73 66 65 69 74 6F 2C  to,Insatisfeito,
00000320  22 4E 65 6D 5F 69 6E 73-61 74 69 73 66 65 69 74  "Nem_insatisfeit
00000330  6F 2C 5F 6E 65 6D 5F 73-61 74 69 73 66 65 69 74  o,_nem_satisfeit
00000340  6F 22 2C 49 6E 73 61 74-69 73 66 65 69 74 6F 2C  o",Insatisfeito,
00000350  4D 75 69 74 6F 5F 73 61-74 69 73 66 65 69 74 6F  Muito_satisfeito
00000360  2C 49 6E 73 61 74 69 73-66 65 69 74 6F 2C 49 6E  ,Insatisfeito,In
00000370  73 61 74 69 73 66 65 69-74 6F 2C 53 61 74 69 73  satisfeito,Satis
00000380  66 65 69 74 6F 2C 53 61-74 69 73 66 65 69 74 6F  feito,Satisfeito
00000390  2C 4E 61 5F 6D CC A9 64-69 61 2C 4D 65 6C 68 6F  ,Na_m..dia,Melho
000003A0  72 5F 61 67 6F 72 61 2C-22 44 69 66 69 63 69 6C  r_agora,"Dificil
000003B0  20 64 65 20 64 69 7A 65-72 2C 20 70 6F 69 73 20   de dizer, pois 
000003C0  6E 61 6F 20 73 65 69 20-6F 20 71 75 65 20 6F 20  nao sei o que o 
000003D0  61 6E 6F 20 6D 65 20 72-65 73 65 72 76 61 22 2C  ano me reserva",
000003E0  2C 75 75 69 64 3A 66 63-32 34 66 62 38 39 2D 35  ,uuid:fc24fb89-5
000003F0  34 63 30 2D 34 39 66 34-2D 61 31 36 31 2D 35 64  4c0-49f4-a161-5d
00000400  64 34 63 63 39 62 37 39-65 39 0D 0A              d4cc9b79e9..
```

...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Becky

Comment: Whatever notepad says, `0xcc 0xc1` **is** an invalid sequence in utf8. Try to hexdump the first lines in the file to see what is actually in the file.

Comment: Try LATIN9 (or the other 8859s) or CP1252 (or the others, such as CP950) The problem is that cca4, cca3 *could* be valid utf8 (in which case you would have mixed encoding)